# Using ROW_NUMBER() OVER() in subquery

Tags: sql, db2, db2-400

I'm encountering a problem, actually I'm using a query like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as VAL_RRN,
         T1.FIELD1 AS FIELD1,
         T1.FIELD2 AS FIELD2 
     FROM 
         MYTABLE1 AS T1) AS subquery 
WHERE 
    VAL_RRN >= X
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

This query is used to display 10 results at one time to the user, and the `X` variable is used with a scroll system to let the user navigate through the results.

This query works well (but I don't know if this is the best way to do it).

Anyway, what I actually need to do is a little different:

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER() as VAL_RRN,
         T1.FIELD1 AS FIELD1,
         T1.FIELD2 AS FIELD2,
         COALESCE((SELECT '1'
                   FROM MYTABLE1 AS T2 
                   WHERE T1.FIELD1 = T2.FIELD2 FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY), '0') AS FIELD3 FROM MYTABLE1 AS T1) AS subquery 
WHERE 
     VAL_RRN >= X
FETCH FIRST 10 ROWS ONLY
```

The `COALESCE` clause is used to know if one row has others rows referencing it.

In `MYTABLE1` the `FIELD1` is the primary key and the `FIELD2` is a Foreign Key defined with:

```
CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME FOREIGN KEY                            
  (FIELD2) REFERENCES MYTABLE (FIELD1) ON DELETE SET NULL
```

the `MYTABLE` table can have row which references other rows.

But when I'm using the second type of query, the actual value of `row_number() over()` is completely random, and I don't know why. I have tried to use `VALUE()` instead of `COALESCE()` but this doesn't seem to work, any ideas?

Comment: Are you selecting this data into a different program? What are you using to display the data? RPG or a web service?

Comment: What release & TR# are you on?

Comment: I'm using RPG to display the data, And i'm on release V7R2M0 with TR level: 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `row_number() over(order by ...)`.
Row enumeration is unpredictable otherwise.

Comment: Actually, you should use some another paging way not re-issuing the same query again, if possible. This way is easy to implement, but it may be not suitable for large number of users / data volume. Try to use a scrollable cursor instead.

Comment: I'll try to use `DECLARE CURSORNAME SENSITIVE DYNAMIC SCROLL CURSOR` but doesn't it lock the data if multiple users works on the same data ?

Comment: This depends on the [isolation level](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0004121.html) you use. If you know how other users access your tables, the [Lock type compatibility](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/r0005274.html) table may help you understand the impact...

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you might want to consider whether to use `RRN(T1)` instead of `ROW_NUMBER()`.

But as Mark B said, you should always use an ORDER BY clause with `ROW_NUMBER()` to prevent an unpredictable sequencing of rows returned.  If there is no appropriate column to order by, you might `ORDER BY RRN(T1)`.

Comment: `RRN(T1)` values may not be sequential, so, its values need to be re-enumerated as well. Moreover, this function exists in `DB2 for IBM i` only. It doesn't exist in `DB2 for Z/OS` and `Db2 for LUW`.

Comment: Re-enumerating with ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY  RRN(T1)) will result in a contiguous sequence of numbers, although it might not necessarily represent the arrival sequence.  The question is tagged db2-400, so IBM i specific answers are appropriate, but it is helpful to others to point out which platforms it applies to, so thank you.